# Move Windows one pixel at the time using the keyboard?

Tags: windows

By default, in Windows, when you right-click a window title bar and select "move", it will allow you to move the window using the arrow keys. The thing is, Windows are moved several pixels each time you press an arrow key.

So, can this be set to move the window 1 pixel each time?

Also, are there any 3rd party programs that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hold down the `Ctrl` key while pressing the arrows for single-pixel control.  You can press and release during the move (or resize) as needed to switch between jumping and single pixel.

Comment: Awesome, I can't believe this feature was already there. Thanks

Comment: It actually goes back at least to Windows 2.0.  I think the jump size is still 10 pixels, too.

Comment: Sadly it's not possible to move the window out of the screen. It will jump right back :-(

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot, great answer, though more specifically, for English language Windows 7 shell layout on Window's windows that are **NOT** "Maximized"/"in full screen mode":
<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>-><kbd>M</kbd>-><kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ARROW KEYS</kbd>-><kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Example: to move a window some pixels to the right: Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> and <kbd>SPACE</kbd> together. Press <kbd>M</kbd>. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> the number of pixels you want to move. Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to lock the window.

Tip: press <kbd>ESC</kbd> instead of <kbd>ENTER</kbd> if you want to reset the window you're moving.