# Ability to nudge windows using shortcut keys in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, window

I absolutely love using the keyboard for doing things and use Win7's <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>, etc a lot. They save so much time.

However, a friend of mine who uses [Fluxbox](http://fluxbox.org/) for a window manager has shortcuts for nudging windows by a few pixels in a given direction. I would very much like to do the same - does anyone know of software of built-in functionality to do this in Windows 7?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/262372/move-windows-one-pixel-at-the-time-using-the-keyboard - this question is about a pure keyboard shortcut, while the other involves a mouse. Please open it back up.

Comment: @studiohack Commenting with your name to bring your attention back to this.

Comment: Well, the answer would be to use alt+space to emulate right clicking on the title bar, and m to select move, followed by the answer above.

Comment: Damn, I'm already used to Alt-Space being the Launchy shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WindowSpace](http://www.ntwind.com/software/windowspace.html) provides this functionality. See http://www.ntwind.com/software/windowspace/moving-and-resizing.html

Comment: Works like a charm. It's not free, but it does the job. I'd prefer a free alternative, but I'll take this for now.